# How to create new cell in UICollectionView without 'NSInternalInconsistencyException' error

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

How do I create a new cell without this error

```
'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'attempt to insert item 2 into section 0, but there are only 2 items in section 0 after the update'
```

Here is the code to create new cell

```
@IBAction func SetDate(sender: AnyObject) {

   let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
    let day = dateTimePicker.date
    let datestring = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(day)
    addDateToArray(datestring)

    let text = textField.text
    addSinceLabelToArray(text!)

    let image = userDefault.objectForKey("image") as! String
    addThemeToImagesArray(image)

    print(dateTimePicker.date)
    print(Globals.datesArray)

    dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)

}
```

Here is how the date from the previous code is used in my app

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(reuseIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! MyCollectionViewCell

    cell.sinceLabel.text = Globals.sinceLabelArray[indexPath.item]
    cell.myBackground.image = UIImage(named: String(Globals.imagesArray[indexPath.item]))

    let day = Globals.datesArray[indexPath.item]
    let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"

    let date1: NSDate = dateFormatter.dateFromString(day)!
        let diffDateComponents = NSCalendar.currentCalendar().components([NSCalendarUnit.Day], fromDate: date1, toDate: date2, options: NSCalendarOptions.init(rawValue: 0))
        cell.dayCountLabel.text = String("\(abs(diffDateComponents.day))")

    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()

    return cell
}
```

Here is how I am reloading data

```
func loadList(notification: NSNotification){
    let count = Globals.datesArray.count
    let index = count > 0 ? count - 1 : count
    let indexPath = NSIndexPath(forItem: index, inSection: 0)
    collectionView!.insertItemsAtIndexPaths([indexPath])

}
```

Here is the code for determining number of cells to make

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return count
}

var count = Globals.datesArray.count as Int
```

Some extra details: 
(1) The SetDate() saves string to three static var arrays, within a struct.
(2) Those arrays are empty, to my knowledge.

Thanks.

Comment: Where are you reloading the data? What code are you using for that?

Comment: Hey Sam, just made an edit.

Comment: You can just use collectionView!.reloadData(), but if you really want to just add that index then you have to do it in a batch update

Comment: Could you give me an example?

Comment: The error message tells you that you inserted item 2 but the `numberOfItemsInSection` function returned 2. Rather than 3. You should really avoid the use of globals and you should provide some information on what changed in your NSNotification as your current code looks like a bit of a hack

Comment: @Paulw11 I need to save the strings in an array I can access from different views, what else besides globals can I use. Btw, what do you mean by "bit of a hack'?

Comment: You should use a singleton object if it needs to be accessed everywhere

Comment: You can use a singleton or a,property of your app delegate and rather than trying to coordinate multiple arrays you should use an array of structs or classes. It looks like a hack since it has conditional code and if your array is empty you insert an item anyway. Your notification should be specific as to what happened to your data model and which item was affected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace your code in loadList with just

```
collectionView!.reloadData()
```

or if you want to do it as a batch update :

```
    collectionView.performBatchUpdates({
        self.collectionView!.insertItemsAtIndexPaths([indexPath])
        }, completion: nil)
```

Comment: At the point you call this, has your data source been updated?

Comment: The arrays? Sorry, I'm still new to coding in general.

Comment: Yeah, whatever is used for the count in the function     numberOfItemsInSection

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116165/discussion-between-khoury-and-sam).

Comment: The solution should be simple based on the code you have now posted and I will reply here in case someone else has the same issue in the future. In the numberOfItemsInSection function: return Globals.datesArray.count. This way it will be calculated whenever needed instead of upon initialisation

Comment: Works perfectly, Thank you